# Retrieve array from javascript response

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

I have a PHP file that responds with a similar javascript response to below.

```
var count = 0;
var actors = [];
var directors = [];
var movies = ["7​/n​/n# L<DxJ", "7x​/nx​/nxlNTv", "(N​/lN​/lNUnNTv", "}x​/Yx​/YxL#llNTv", "}​/Y​/Y<L<J", "O​/u​;uiLY<J", "@​/J​/JNUL<DxJ"];
var hidden = [];
var r_space = null;
var chars = {
    "i": "N",
    "R": "6",
    "u": "T",
    "a": "i",
    "V": "p",
    ">": "a"
};
for (var i in chars) {
    if (i == ' ') r_space = asta[i];
}
```

The movie names are encoded using a simple algorithm using **var chars**. I want to iterate through the **var movies** and get all values in to an array so I can decode them. I tried using below code to split by ";" and then call [3] to get **var movies** and then split it by "," to get each movie name and store it an array but the issues is some words in **var movies** also contain ";".

```
var_array = str(response.content.decode()).split(";")[3][14:-1].split(",")
for va in var_array:
    print(va[1:-1])
```

Is there a different way I can get all values in **var movies** to an array and then decode? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `json` and `re` (regex) modules:

```py
json.loads(re.search("var movies = (?P<movies>\[.+\]);", str(response.content.decode())).group("movies"))
```

This will result in:

```
['7\u200b/n\u200b/n# L<DxJ',
 '7x\u200b/nx\u200b/nxlNTv',
 '(N\u200b/lN\u200b/lNUnNTv',
 '}x\u200b/Yx\u200b/YxL#llNTv',
 '}\u200b/Y\u200b/Y<L<J',
 'O\u200b/u\u200b;uiLY<J',
 '@\u200b/J\u200b/JNUL<DxJ']
```

Then you can simply run a for loop over this list.

Comment: You probably need to split that into `","` first too.

Comment: Thanks Amir for the code. But when I run it I get "JSONDecodeError: Extra data" error. I tried without json.loads and it gives me the results starting with the movies names but it doesn't stop at the end of the array. it also collects the remaining var arrays in the response. Any idea what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: @GeomanYabes Thanks for the comment, Geoman. I am not sure why there is unicode characters in my output, I think it has something to do with the OP's input. Beside that, I ran the code above on the response OP is getting (but as a file and not a url request-response), and it worked fine. I highly appreciate it if you elaborate on using `","`.

Comment: @evildatascientist Thanks for the comment. My guess is that the response you are getting is not the same as you have shown in the question. It might be separated with `\n` or something like that. Are you sure the response is exactly as the question?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani Thanks for the support Amir. The response is the same as I have showed in the question. I have found a solution based on your suggestion. I have ignored the json.loads and have split the array by ";var" and stored it in an array that way I get all content of var movies. Not the most elegant way but it gets the job done for now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try to Use the JavaScript function JSON.parse() to convert text into a JavaScript object and then loop on it to get movies value.

let moviesObject = JSON.parse(movies);

for movie in moviesObject:

```
console.log(va)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I dont know how to implement this correctly.